# Adding Master Authorized Networks in GKE

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, yaml, cluster-computing, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to add masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig cidrblock during gke cluster creation. I am using yaml as my configuration file. For the most part everything work except for when it hit the section in the code for masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig. I get the error below.

ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1570192512938-59414eef672d4-7aad07f0-31e95364]: errors:
- code: CONDITION_NOT_MET
  location: /deployments/cff-prod-clus/resources/prod-cff->$.properties
  message: |
    error: instance type (object) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["array"])
        level: "error"
        schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/schemas/MasterAuthorizedNetworksConfig/properties/cidrBlocks"}
        instance: {"pointer":"/cluster/masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig/cidrBlocks"}
        domain: "validation"
        keyword: "type"
        found: "object"
        expected: ["array"]

I have tried changing the code around with different syntax but I get same results.

```
 ipAllocationPolicy:
        useIpAliases: true
        clusterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.81.224.0/20
        servicesIpv4CidrBlock: 10.81.222.0/23
      masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig:
        enabled: true
        cidrBlocks: 
          displayName: Corporate
          cidrBlock: 10.10.1.0/24
      networkConfig:
        enableIntraNodeVisibility: true
      privateClusterConfig:
        enablePrivateNodes: true
        masterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.81.219.0/28
```

corrected code

```
 ipAllocationPolicy:
        useIpAliases: true
        clusterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.81.224.0/20
        servicesIpv4CidrBlock: 10.81.222.0/23
      masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig:
        enabled: true
        cidrBlocks: 
          - displayName: Corporate
          - cidrBlock: 10.10.1.0/24
      networkConfig:
        enableIntraNodeVisibility: true
      privateClusterConfig:
        enablePrivateNodes: true
        masterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.81.219.0/28
```

Unless this is not available during deployment I was expecting to add that cidrblock to the Master authorized networks.

Comment: Figured it out everyone. Look above at code.

Answer (score 0):

The `masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig.cidrBlocks` field is expecting an array (even if you are only adding a single entry). Each entry must have a `-`. Note that each entry is not necessarily a different line. In your case, you can do the following:

```
      masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig:
        enabled: true
        cidrBlocks: 
          - displayName: Corporate
            cidrBlock: 10.10.1.0/24
```

The displayName and the cidrBlock both belong to the same entry, so no need for dashes on each line. However, if you wanted to add another CIDR, you would add aonther `-` for the next entry